# How to bundle javascript files with one external library with rollup.js?

Tags: javascript, es6-modules, rollupjs

I have created a helloWorld.js file, which uses the object WebFont from the webfontloader package. My goal is to bundle my helloWorld.js file into a bundle.js and then an static web site, which has seperate script tags for the webfont file and the bundle.js file.
The problem is just one line of code in the resulting bundle.js because it creates a prefix I do not want.

My web site should be:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8"> <!-- also save this file as unicode-8 ! -->
<head>
  <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.js"></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/webfont/1.6.26/webfont.js"></script>
  <script src="build/bundle.js"></script>
  <style>            
    h1 {
        color: steelblue;
        font-family: 'Indie Flower', cursive;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <script>
    var myChart = hw.chart("hello world!");

    d3.select("body")
      .append("div")
      .attr("class", "chart")
      .call(myChart);
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

My "./src/helloworld.js" file is here:

```
import * as d3 from "d3";
import { WebFont } from "webfontloader";

// export default function main () {
export function chart (myText) {
  "use strict";

  function displayNice( selection, myText){
    WebFont.load({
      google: { families: ["Indie Flower"]},
      fontactive: function(){ //This is called once font has been rendered in browser
        display(selection, myText);
      },
    });
  } 

  function chartAPI(selection) {
    selection.each(function () {
      displayNice(this, myText);
    });
  }

  function display(_selection, _myText) {
    d3.select(_selection)
      .append("div")
      .attr("class", "hwChart")
      .append("h1")
      .text(_myText);
  }
  return chartAPI;
}
```

and my rollup.config.js looks like:

```
// rollup.config.js
// import nodeResolve from 'rollup-plugin-node-resolve';
import babel from "rollup-plugin-babel";

export default {
  entry: "index.js",
  dest: "build/bundle.js",
  format: "umd",
  moduleName: "hw",
  globals: { 
    "d3": "d3",
    "webfontloader": "webfontloader"
  },
  plugins: [
    /*
    nodeResolve({ 
      jsnext: true, 
      main: true}),
      */

    babel({
      exclude: "node_modules/**"})
  ]
};
```

and my index.js file contains this line:

```
export { chart } from "./src/helloWorld";
```

The resulting bundle.js contains one line which causes the error:

```
(function (global, factory) {
  typeof exports === 'object' && typeof module !== 'undefined' ? factory(exports, require('d3'), require('webfontloader')) :
  typeof define === 'function' && define.amd ? define(['exports', 'd3', 'webfontloader'], factory) :
  (factory((global.hw = global.hw || {}),global.d3,global.webfontloader));
}(this, function (exports,d3,webfontloader) { 'use strict';

  // export default function main () {
  function chart(myText) {
    "use strict";

    function displayNice(selection, myText) {
      webfontloader.WebFont.load({
        google: { families: ["Indie Flower"] },
        fontactive: function fontactive() {
          //This is called once font has been rendered in browser
          display(selection, myText);
        }
      });
    }

    function chartAPI(selection) {
      selection.each(function () {
        displayNice(this, myText);
      });
    }

    function display(_selection, _myText) {
      d3.select(_selection).append("div").attr("class", "hwChart").append("h1").text(_myText);
    }
    return chartAPI;
  }

  exports.chart = chart;

  Object.defineProperty(exports, '__esModule', { value: true });

}));
```

This causes an error, because in the browser there is no webfontloader Object.

How can I adjust the rollup configuration such that I get this:

```
function displayNice(selection, myText) {
  WebFont.load({
```

instead of this:

```
function displayNice(selection, myText) {
  webfontloader.WebFont.load({
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I figured it out, finally!

The above approach needs the following two changes:

- in [rollup.config.js]: add "webfontloader" as external but not as global
- in [helloWorld.js]: change import statement to ìmport Webfont from "webfontloader";

Here are the two files:
helloworld.js:

```
import * as d3 from "d3";
import WebFont from "webfontloader";

// export default function main () {
export function chart (myText) {
  "use strict";

  function displayNice( selection, myText){
    WebFont.load({
      google: { families: ["Indie Flower"]},
      fontactive: function(){ //This is called once font has been rendered in browser
        display(selection, myText);
      },
    });
  } 

  function chartAPI(selection) {
    selection.each(function () {
      displayNice(this, myText);
    });
  }

  function display(_selection, _myText) {
    d3.select(_selection)
      .append("div")
      .attr("class", "hwChart")
      .append("h1")
      .text(_myText);
  }
  return chartAPI;
}
```

and rollup.config.js:

```
// rollup.config.js
// import nodeResolve from 'rollup-plugin-node-resolve';
import babel from "rollup-plugin-babel";

export default {
  entry: "index.js",
  dest: "build/helloWorld.js",
  format: "umd",
  moduleName: "hw",
  globals: { 
    "d3": "d3"
  },
  external: ["webfontloader"],
  plugins: [
    /*
    nodeResolve({ 
      jsnext: true, 
      main: true}),
      */

    babel({
      exclude: "node_modules/**"})
  ]
};
```